# Primefaces Schedule set Start Time and End Time

Tags: java, primefaces

I'm able to set startDate and endDate on primefaces schedule.
My question.
Is it possibile to set startTime and endTime ? For example: from 11:30am to 12:30 pm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use p:calendar:

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarView.date10}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

taken from [official showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml).